# Need to generate pulse when a signal crosses zero point in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an input signal I=sin(omega*t). Which simulink model do I use in order to get a pulse every time the signal crosses zero-point?

Comment: [This block](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/detectrisepositive.html) with its output triggering a pulse generator comes to mind.

Comment: Your post was very helpful thank you.

Comment: @mikkola And how could we trigger a pulse generator? The Simulink block named "Pulse Generator" does not have any input terminals.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion:
[image]

The transport delay block makes a delayed version of input signal. You need to make the sampling rate of this block low. Then, signs of original and delayed signals are subtracted. If signs are equal you get 0, if signs are different (zero is crossed) then you get +-2. You take absolute value and divide signal by 2 to get:

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify the parameters used for generating sine and for the transport delay function so that i can better understand the proposed model. Thank You.

Comment: Delay was set to 0.01, sine function was unchanged. Time step for the whole model was 0.001 and stop time was set to 50

Comment: Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I find one another way to do this:

[image]

Upper part of image - it's all simulink model, bottom part - is a resettable subsystem.

Result:
[image]

Constant `1` is an amplitude of pulse, `3` in Compare To Constant block - is a length of pulse.